# Script to build a set of jobs, wait until they finish and write a report about them

Tags: jenkins

I'm planning to write a script that would choose a set of Jenkins jobs with a regexp, start their builds and wait until they finish. If most of them fail, I want to change some global env vars (I already know how to do this) and build them again. Then I want to collect the test results and format it into a nice report.

I can't put this into the individual jobs' post-build actions, I need info about all of them to write the report and to do the rebuilding.

My current idea is to use the Jenkins REST API, but before I do so: is this already implemented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

1. Give a look at Multi-Job plugin and see if it fits your requirement.
2. Else go with REST API.

Because unique requirement of our build process I had to use jenkins cli :

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://<jenkinsURL> build <job-name> -s <parameters if any>
```

The trailing -s makes it wait till the job is complete.